# classcastexception - trying to implement toptoche searchablespinner

Tags: android

in my previous app I used a searchable spinner by toptoche dependencies. (my previous app is very similar to this one just using recyclerview and cardviews instead) so I went through my code and just replaced the Spinner object with SearchableSpinner. However when I run the app and press the FAB (when cardview is suppose to show) I get an classcastexception. Have I missed something out here?

**Error**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner cannot be cast to com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
        at com.app.supermarketaislefinder.ProductAdapter$ProductViewHolder.<init>(ProductAdapter.java:91)
        at com.app.supermarketaislefinder.ProductAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ProductAdapter.java:41)
        at com.app.supermarketaislefinder.ProductAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ProductAdapter.java:20)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4481)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**ProductAdapter.java** wherethe error seems to be in

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {


    //this context we will use to inflate the layout
    private Context mCtx;
    private SearchableSpinner spinner;

    //we are storing all the products in a list
    private List<Product> productList;

    //getting the context and product list with constructor
    public ProductAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_products, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //getting the product of the specified position
        Product product = productList.get(position);

        //binding the data with the viewholder views


        //MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(mCtx, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, Product.spinnerItemsList);
        //spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (mCtx, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Product.getSpinnerItemsList());
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        holder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }



    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        SearchableSpinner spinner;
        EditText editText;
        TextView textView5;
        CheckBox checkBox;



        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            textView5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        }
    }
}
```

**and my activity code for reference**

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {



    //a list to store all the products
    List<Product> productList;

    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    Product mProduct;
    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);

        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
         CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);

       final List<String>  mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();


        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();

///s/Di it work?
        //I click the dropdown and the items show! I select an item, then i press fab to get another cardview
        //I select an item from there , it shows
        //i add another cardview then all the spinners are cleared?
        //Hmm its because when the recyclerview item is out of the screen scope its recycled now you need to find a solution of
        //storing the state of spinner for selected item
        //i had a previous app which did exactly the same as this just without recyclerview and cardview. but with spinner i think
        //i used sharedpreferences or something. i can have a look at my old code and see


        //I will suggest you to make an array and then store the selected item by the index of the item in recyclerview





      final SearchableSpinner spinner;
      final EditText editText;
      final CheckBox checkBox;
      final TextView textView5;

      spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
      editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
      checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
      textView5 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);

      final ProductAdapter  adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList);

        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                List<Product> mProductList = new ArrayList<>();
                productList.add(mProduct);
                if(adapter != null)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Handle the empty adapter here

            }
        });


       /* //TODO Add the spinner on item selected listener to get selected items
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                String currentItem = mSpinnerItems.get(position);
                String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                //TODO you can use the above aisle number to add to your text view
                //mTextviews.get(mTextviews.size() -1).setText(aisleNumber);
                textView5.setText(aisleNumber);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                //  do nothing
            }
        });*/






        //setting adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);






    }




    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {
// The problem with your adapter is solved now you need to do some work here its giving an error while reading the file
            //why is it giving an error because it use to work fine before I added cardview and recyclerview
            //Is the file there?
            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable

                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);

                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: check your xml in which spinner is present , change to searchable there

Comment: ah gotcha! Thanks. I changed that but now when I click the searchable spinner in my app, i do not see any items in the list....

Comment: then the problem is in theme now like as dropdownresource, you may find similar questions related to your problem

Comment: I have tried searching but havent found similar questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are doing stuff in your activity while your Spinner object is present in your adapter, So there are two ways one either access the item from adapter inside the activity or implement the method inside the adapterView.

```java
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {



    //a list to store all the products
    List<Product> productList;

    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    Product mProduct;
    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);

        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
         CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);

       final List<String>  mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();


        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();

      final ProductAdapter  adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList);

        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                List<Product> mProductList = new ArrayList<>();
                productList.add(mProduct);
                if(adapter != null)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Handle the empty adapter here

            }
        });







        //setting adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);






    }




    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {
// The problem with your adapter is solved now you need to do some work here its giving an error while reading the file
            //why is it giving an error because it use to work fine before I added cardview and recyclerview
            //Is the file there?
            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable

                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);

                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }



}
```